# Realm with flutter - unmanaged object

Tags: database, flutter, dart, realm

I have a question about the realm database for flutter that I want to use locally.

Background: The objects that are read from the realm database are managed by the realm database => object.isManaged = true. If I work here with a data layer and domain layer and convert the objects in the domain type, change a property and convert back to the data type, the objet is now unmanaged => object.isManaged = false. So I can't delete and change the object in database anymore. And I get the following error when deleting: "Realm error : Cannot delete an unmanaged object".

Question: Is there a pragmatic solution for this - without giving up the different layers (data and domain)?

Thanks in advance.

I think if I can make sure the data is already part of the real database, I should be able to force the object to object.isManaged = true. Or I can create a managed object without new access to the database itself.

I have added a picture as further explanation. My goal is to have no dependency on Realm within the Presentation / UI layer.

[image]

Here a the models the domain models:

```
class ShoppingListItem {
  String uuid;
  int amount;

  bool done;
  Grocery grocery;

  ShoppingListItem({
    required this.uuid,
    required this.amount,
    required this.done,
    required this.grocery,
  });
}

class Grocery {
  int? barcode;

  String? name;
  String? brand;

  Grocery({
    this.barcode,
    this.name,
    this.brand,
  });
}
```

And the models from the Data layer which are also used for Realm

```
    @RealmModel()
class _ShoppingListItemData {
  @PrimaryKey()
  late String uuid;
  late int? amount;
  late bool? done;
  late _GroceryData? grocery;
}

@RealmModel(ObjectType.embeddedObject)
class _GroceryData {
  late int? barcode;
  late String? name;
  late String? brand;
}
```

And here are the methods which transform the data toData and back toDomain

```
class Interface {
  static ShoppingListItem toDomain(ShoppingListItemData shoppingListItemData) {
    return ShoppingListItem(
        uuid: shoppingListItemData.uuid,
        amount: shoppingListItemData.amount ?? 1,
        done: shoppingListItemData.done ?? false,
        grocery: Grocery(
            barcode: shoppingListItemData.grocery?.barcode ?? 0,
            name: shoppingListItemData.grocery?.name));
  }

  static ShoppingListItemData fromDomain(ShoppingListItem shoppingListItem) {
    return ShoppingListItemData(shoppingListItem.uuid,
        amount: shoppingListItem.amount,
        done: shoppingListItem.done,
        grocery: GroceryData(
            barcode: shoppingListItem.grocery.barcode,
            brand: shoppingListItem.grocery.brand,
            name: shoppingListItem.grocery.name));
  }
}
```

As soon the data are copied to Domain an and than back to Data layer the *object.isManaged = false* and therefore deletion or modification to the realm data base can not be applied.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; What does - *convert the objects* - mean and why do you want to make an unmanaged copy of the object when you modifying the managed object anyway? It's actually fine to do that but just curious. More importantly, what process are you using? Can you include your code and models so we know what that looks like? Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Jay, I have added further clarification.

Comment: Not sure if it's any more clear. What *code* are you using to *convert the objects*? What do the models look like? What's preventing you from say, making an unmanaged copy of an object (so it will have the same data in it's properties). Then when  it comes time to save, update the managed object with the updated data from the unmanaged one? Do the objects have _id properties? If so, the issue is unclear as this task should be straightforward.

Comment: "Then when it comes time to save, update the managed object with the updated data from the unmanaged one? " I think this is exactly my point I am trying to solve. Based on your comment, if I understand correctly, I need to keep the managed objects in a list at a Data layer, so I have the ability to map them back based on the id/uuid for data coming from Domain layer? Or do you have another option / solution in mind?

Comment: Okay, easier solution I think would be to use the method "realm.find(primaryKey)" based on primary key on the Realm DB. Based on that the method should return a managed object which I can update based on data coming from domain.

Comment: *I need to keep the managed objects in a list at a Data layer* nope, not at all. Once it's read in and an unmanaged copy is made, there's no reason to keep the managed object hanging around. Once the unmanaged object is populated (you would know it's key as well), load the Realm object matching that key and update it. That being said, it's really not clear why you're doing any of this. It kinda defeats the purpose and power of Realm; objects are live and as they change, you can update your UI accordingly. It just seems like a lot of extra effort to work around a built in feature.

Comment: Why so? That's a good question  . Then I'll try to explain:
1) Independence from the type of database. So that I can replace it with another one if necessary, without adjusting the presentation and domain layer.
2) To keep the classes of the data (class ShoppingListItem and class Grocery) under my control. So that I can create static constructor etc.  
Since Realm generator creates the classes automatically, I can't add the custom methods as far I see.
Please take into account that I am far from being an expert (yet) in Flutter as well as in Realm or MongoDB and still learning a lot.

Comment: *Independence from the type of database* super GOOD reason. But a few things; models can be created in code so this *Realm generator creates the classes automatically* is not totally accurate; they can contain custom functions. The only thing Realm does (if you're syncing) is to create the models properties on the server that matches (in development mode). Models can be managed or unmanaged and carry the same code (e.g. custom methods). It's extraordinarily difficult to replace a database as then you loose that feature set. So really, don't bother coding for that as it's not worth it IMO

Comment: I am also using the same approach as described by @Konst . I am using this approach to enable my app work in online and offline mode.  In online mode, all the data is synced to the Mongodb on atlas. And in Offline mode it is saved locally using realm. Now a user can modify the data and update the data locally and sync when he is done or is in good connectivity region. The data is not specific to any user it's all syncing to the main Mongdb. Please guide if this is not a good approach to solve this problem.